# Is there a name for a symmetric matrix of diagonals?

Tags: matrices, terminology, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

I have a symmetric matrix with three diagonal elements, two of which are off the main diagonal.  I wanted to ask if there was a name for this type of matrix.  If it helps, I couldn't find it in Wikipedia's "List of Named Matricies."
$$X=\left[\begin{array}{cccccccc}
a_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_4 \\
b_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & b_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_7 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & b_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a_8 \\
\end{array}\right]$$

Is there any "special" name for this type of Matrix?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix will do.

Comment: It is a [banded matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix), but more special since there are only $3$ non-zero diagonals. I'd call it a "symmetric banded matrix with three bands", but someone might have already come up with a better name. Also, note that by permuting the rows and columns of the matrix in the question, one can form a block-diagonal matrix whose diagonal blocks are tridiagonal.

Comment: I don't know a precise name for matrices with the structure you describe.  However the example, an $8\times 8$ matrix, has a useful *block structure* comprised of $4\times 4$ diagonal blocks.  Is that of interest?

Comment: a certain permutation matrix, call it $P,$ ( also symmetric)  takes your $X$  to $PXP$  which is tridiagonal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix  I see, same comment by @JimmyK4542   My intended $P$  permutes elements $2,5$  then also permutes $4,7.$  As these transpositions commute....